# Getting Azure network information using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network

I am attempting to put a script together that will get the following information and store it in a custom object.

```
SubscriptionName
ResourceGroupName
VNetName
AddressSpace
SubnetName
SubnetAddressSpace
NSG
RouteTable
```

At the moment, the script below can get some of the info stored in a csv file

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$path  = "C:\output\vnet_test.csv"

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) { 
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    Get-AzVirtualNetwork | 
        Select-Object  `
            @{label='SubscriptionName'; expression={$Sub.Name}}, `
            ResourceGroupName, `
            Name, `
            @{label='AddressSpace'; expression={$_.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes}}, `
            @{label='SubnetName'; expression={$_.Subnets.Name}}, `
            @{label='SubnetAddressSpace'; expression={$_.Subnets.AddressPrefix}} |
        Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII  -Append
}
```

It doesn't store the data within a custom object so that I can transform as I like, it doesnt also get the NSG and routing information.

To get the routing and NSG information, from the research I did I came across.

```
$nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
Write-Host "   nsg: " $nsg.Name
$networksecuritygroup = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsg -ResourceGroupName $nsg.ResourceGroupName
}
$rts = Get-Azroutetable
foreach ($rt in $rts) {
Write-Host "  rt: " $rt.Name
$routetableinfo = Get-Azroutetable -Name $rt -ResourceGroupName $rt.ResourceGroupName
}
```

What I am struggling to do is putting it together as a single script that will store the results in a custom object and export to csv. The below script isnt quite correct.

$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$path = "C:\output\vnet_test2.csv"

$results = @()

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null

```
$virtualNetworks = Get-AzVirtualNetwork

foreach ($vnet in $virtualNetworks) {
    $nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $vnet.ResourceGroupName
    $routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $vnet.ResourceGroupName

    $vnetInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
        SubscriptionName    = $Sub.Name
        ResourceGroupName   = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
        VirtualNetworkName  = $vnet.Name
        AddressSpace        = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ', '
        SubnetInfo          = @()
        NSGs                = @($nsgs.Name)
        RouteTables         = @($routeTables.Name)
    }

    foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
        $subnetInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubnetName          = $subnet.Name
            SubnetAddressSpace  = $subnet.AddressPrefix
        }
        $vnetInfo.SubnetInfo += $subnetInfo
    }

    $results += $vnetInfo
}
```

}

$results | Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII

What are the problems ?

The following columns `SubnetInfo,NSGs,RouteTables` comes back with `System.Object[]` on the csv file, this is because it contains further information for example one vnet might have multiple subnets, on the CSV file I would like a single entry for each subnet, extract the address space and also display the route table. This is a 1 to many relationship type of data and I am struggling to have it as a single view showing me all the columns, once I have this in a csv file I can use excel to slice & dice the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below modified script for your expected result :

```
$report = @()

$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$path = "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\test\khan.csv"

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    
    $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
    foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {
        foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
            $vnetInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                SubscriptionName    = $Sub.Name
                ResourceGroupName   = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
                VNetName            = $vnet.Name
                AddressSpace        = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ','
                SubnetName          = $subnet.Name
                SubnetAddressSpace  = $subnet.AddressPrefix -join ','
                NSG                 = ""
                RouteTable          = ""
            }

            $nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $vnet.ResourceGroupName
            foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
                $vnetInfo.NSG += $nsg.Name + ","
            }

            $routetables = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $vnet.ResourceGroupName
            foreach ($routetable in $routetables) {
                $vnetInfo.RouteTable += $routetable.Name + ","
            }

            $report += $vnetInfo
        }
    }
}

# Export to CSV
$report | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

`Output:`

[image]

[image]

```
SubscriptionName   : FTE XXXXXX
ResourceGroupName  : Aks-rg-test
VNetName           : spoke1
AddressSpace       : 172.168.10.0/24
SubnetName         : sub1
SubnetAddressSpace : 172.168.10.0/24
NSG                : None (or N/A if applicable)
RouteTable         : None (or N/A if applicable)

SubscriptionName   : FTEXXXXXXX
ResourceGroupName  : imran
VNetName           : vnet1
AddressSpace       : 10.0.0.0/16,172.0.0.0/16
SubnetName         : default
SubnetAddressSpace : 10.0.0.0/24
NSG                : vm1-nsg,
RouteTable         : tr1,
```

### Update

I have modified script retrieves the NSG and routing information separately and adds it to the custom object and correctly formats the output for the `SubnetInfo`, NSGs, and Route Tables columns.

- Added a new custom object called `$vnetInfo` to store the information for each virtual network and subnet
- loop to retrieve the `NSG` information for each virtual network and subnet and add same loop to retrieve the `routing` information for each virtual network and subnet, this loop retrieves the NSG & routing tables associated with the virtual network and adds them to the `$vnetInfo` object.
- Modified the output for the `SubnetInfo, NSGs, and RouteTables columns` to correctly format the data.

Comment: Would you say something about the differences from the OP's code? Just saying "here's your code" misses out on a learning opportunity for all readers.

Comment: Sure I will update it

Comment: @Imran thank you for the script, works well. I do have an issue, some of the NSG and route tables are not in thesame resource group as the vnet, this mean that some of the reports have empty nsg/route table information. Is there anything that I can do here ? Thinking about it, looks like I need to get the resource group for every subnet, then when `Get-AzRouteTable ` runs, pass that resource group to it rather then vnet resource group.

Comment: sure @learner can you raise new question along with detail explanation and screenshot if possible so that community will address that.

Comment: @Imran I raised a follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77665800/how-to-retrieve-subnet-and-route-table-information