# How to retrieve subnet and route table information

Tags: powershell, azure-virtual-network

Following on from my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659799/getting-azure-network-information-using-powershell), I have a working solution however it requires some fine tuning. What I have noticed is that some of the route tables & nsg's are not on thesame resource group as that of the vnet, when `Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup` and `Get-AzRouteTable` run, they are looking in the wrong place and thus coming up with blank NSG/route table information.

At the moment, I know `$subnet_rg` is incorrect as that does not return the resource group, I will also require the resource group for the route table too.
Is there a way to remove the trailing comma at the end of certain columns ?

```
$report = @()

$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$path = "C:\Users\xxxx\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\test\khan.csv"

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null
    
    $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
    foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {
        foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
            $vnetInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                SubscriptionName    = $Sub.Name
                ResourceGroupName   = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
                VNetName            = $vnet.Name
                AddressSpace        = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ','
                SubnetName          = $subnet.Name
                SubnetAddressSpace  = $subnet.AddressPrefix -join ','
                NSG                 = ""
                RouteTable          = ""
                RoutePropagationDisabled = ""
            }

            $subnet_rg = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnet.Name -VirtualNetwork $vnet

            $nsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $subnet_rg
            foreach ($nsg in $nsgs) {
                $vnetInfo.NSG += $nsg.Name + ","
            }

            $routetables = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $subnet_rg
            foreach ($routetable in $routetables) {
                $vnetInfo.RouteTable += $routetable.Name + ","
                $vnetInfo.RoutePropagationDisabled += $routetable.DisableBgpRoutePropagation 

            }

            $report += $vnetInfo
        }
    }
}

# Export to CSV
$report | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I have noticed is that some of the route tables & nsg's are not on the same resource group as that of the vnet

You can use the updated script below, which directly uses `$subnet.NetworkSecurityGroup` and `$subnet.RouteTable` to check for associated NSGs and route tables.

```
$report = @()

$subs = Get-AzSubscription
$path = "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive - Microsoft\Desktop\test\khan.csv"

foreach ($Sub in $Subs) {
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $Sub.Name | Out-Null

    $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
    foreach ($vnet in $vnets) {
        foreach ($subnet in $vnet.Subnets) {
            $vnetInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
                SubscriptionName        = $Sub.Name
                ResourceGroupName       = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
                VNetName                = $vnet.Name
                AddressSpace            = $vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes -join ','
                SubnetName              = $subnet.Name
                SubnetAddressSpace      = $subnet.AddressPrefix -join ','
                NSG                     = ""
                RouteTable              = ""
                RoutePropagationDisabled = ""
            }

            # Check if the subnet has an associated NSG
            if ($subnet.NetworkSecurityGroup -ne $null) {
                $vnetInfo.NSG = $subnet.NetworkSecurityGroup.Id.Split('/')[-1]
            }

            # Check if the subnet has an associated route table
            if ($subnet.RouteTable -ne $null) {
                $vnetInfo.RouteTable = $subnet.RouteTable.Id.Split('/')[-1]
                $vnetInfo.RoutePropagationDisabled = $subnet.RouteTable.DisableBgpRoutePropagation
            }

            $report += $vnetInfo
        }
    }
}

# Export to CSV
$report | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

> This script first gets all Azure subscriptions that the user has access to and then loops through each subscription. For each subscription, it selects the subscription and gets all virtual networks. For each virtual network, it loops through each subnet and creates a PowerShell custom object with the information mentioned above. If the subnet has an associated NSG or route table, it adds that information to the custom object. Finally, it adds the custom object to an array.

***Output***:

```
SubscriptionName         : xxxxx
ResourceGroupName        : imran
VNetName                 : vnet1
AddressSpace             : 10.0.0.0/16,172.0.0.0/16
SubnetName               : default
SubnetAddressSpace       : 10.0.0.0/24
NSG                      : vm1-nsg
RouteTable               :#If routetable not associate with any subnet it show null
RoutePropagationDisabled : 

SubscriptionName         : xxxxx
ResourceGroupName        : imran
VNetName                 : vnet1
AddressSpace             : 10.0.0.0/16,172.0.0.0/16
SubnetName               : sub1
SubnetAddressSpace       : 172.0.0.0/16
NSG                      : Khan-NSG
RouteTable               : route2
RoutePropagationDisabled : False
```

[image]

[image]

So, in my resource group I have one vnet with 2 subnet, 1st subnet is associated with same resource group NSG (VM1-NSG) and another subnet is associated with different resource group NSG (khan-NSG) and another resource route table (Route2) as shown in output.

[image]

Comment: script works fine, thank you. Just one thing to bear in mind, sometimes the route table is not in thesame resource group as the vnet, so its better to get the subnet resource group, then run `Get-AzRouteTable` to get the routing information.